# Need to setup port forwarding to port 5552 on azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, portforwarding

I am doing penetration testing with a RAT (Remote Access Tool) program and it requires a listening  port to be open for its use (no preference, but i'm using port 5552). I was looking for that function on the Microsoft Azure Portal but I couldn't find anything.

Basically, I want to keep open my RDP port (3389) and at the same time forward incoming requests for port 5552 to the VM (I don't know if this makes sense to anyone but...).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using an ARM VM so I would suggest using a Load Balancer. You could have traffic come into say 10.0.0.1:5552 and have it redirected to the VMs IP say 20.0.0.1:3389

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview

We used to have better functionality around this on Classic VMs but I have not see it transition to ARM yet.

Comment: Yes I remember it on the classic view... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Its not letting me add the vm's public ip address to the load balancer